# Does human made global warming of atmosphere drive the increase of volcanic and tectonic activity?

Tags: estimation, geophysics, climate-science

I read in the handbook that the heat transfer coefficient between magma and soil is very small. What then is the mechanism of the predominant influence of global warming due to greenhouse emissions on volcanic and tectonic activity?

Comment: 1. What 'handbook'? 2. Why do you think there is any influence of global warming on tectonic activity at all? 3. What relevance does the 'human made" in the title have to the content of the question? 4. Might this question be better suited for [earthscience.SE] than Physics?

Comment: 1. Don't really remember, some old Russian scientific book from USSR. 2. I do not know, I am asking. 3. Human made - the CO2 release by human activity. This factor we can stop. 4. Yes, thank you. Please do not delete the problem.